# Ubuntu One problem with instalation

Tags: 10.10, installation, ubuntu-one

i've tried to install Ubuntu One again and i run into probem.
I's trying to do it with Ubuntu software center - instaled ubuntu one but i can not find ubuntu one in menu so a marked to install ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk and i saw this - "ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk:
 Wymaga: ubuntuone-installer  but it is not installable"
I downloaded ubuntuone installer but i can not install it -  E: Package 'ubuntuone-installer' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 1):

Try from a terminal: `sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-installer ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk`

Make sure you have the "universe" repository check in "Software Sources"

As noted in my comments, you probably want this though:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-client-gnome
```

Comment: i tried it before 
[..]Gotowe
Pakiet ubuntuone-installer nie ma dostępnej wersji, ale odnosi się do niego inny pakiet.
Zazwyczaj oznacza to, że pakietu brakuje, został zastąpiony przez inny
pakiet lub nie jest dostępny przy pomocy obecnie ustawionych źródeł.

E: Package 'ubuntuone-installer' has no installation candidate

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Though, I'm looking through the repositories and you might want ubuntuone-client-gnome instead of ubuntuone-installer. ubuntuone-client-gnome is available in the "main" (default) repository.

Comment: i check it and i see that i have installed ubuntuone-client-gnome

Comment: OK, then just make sure you enable to universe repository in the Software Sources (or Community maintained open source software)

Comment: it's enable. :(

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` Does that put out anything weird?

Comment: W: GPG error: http://packages.medibuntu.org maverick Release: Następujące podpisy nie mogły zostać zweryfikowane z powodu braku klucza publicznego: NO_PUBKEY 2EBC26B60C5A2783
W: Nie udało się pobrać http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuone/nightlie/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Nie udało się pobrać http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuone/nightlie/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

Comment: take out that PPA by either removing /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuone-nightly.list or by removing the entry from your /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: can't find /../ubuntuone-nightly.list also can find adequate enter in sources.list

Comment: Sorry, it was ubuntuone-nightlie.list. Either way, just have a look in /etc/apt/sources.list and find one that looks like that - I might be a little off on my PPA to filename conversion. It's probably the only use that has ubuntuone in the name.

Comment: ok, i delete it. what now?

Comment: do a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-installer ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk`

Comment: Budowanie drzewa zależności       
Odczyt informacji o stanie... Gotowe
E: Nie udało się odnaleźć pakietu ubuntuone-installer
E: Nie udało się odnaleźć pakietu ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk
means - can not find packet ubuntuone-installer and the same to control panel

Comment: Wt.. and apt-get update http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuone/ppa/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Nie udało się pobrać http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuone/ppa/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

Comment: Dang, you're all kinds of messed up. Either remove that entry from your /etc/apt/sources.list or find the file that contains it in /etc/apt/sources.list.d. You will need root permissions for either of these tasks. Hint: (Alt+F2) gksu gedit

Comment: There's no entry about ubuntuone in  /etc/apt/sources.list and i think i remove all ubuntuone files from sources.list.d. Little confused. what am i doin?:)

Comment: Hi, i deal with installing ubuntu one by using pugre. Now i've got next one;/ I run ubuntu one from system>pref>ubuntu one and ubuntuone sso doesnt appear so i cant log in;/